# How can I manually register distributions with pkg_resources?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, setuptools, pkg-resources

I'm trying to get a package installed on Google App Engine.  The package relies rather extensively on `pkg_resources`, but there's no way to run `setup.py` on App Engine.

There's no platform-specific code in the source, however, so it's no problem to just zip up the source and include those in the system path.  And I've gotten a version of `pkg_resources` installed and working as well.

The only problem is getting the package actually *registered* with `pkg_resources` so when it calls `iter_entry_points` it can find the appropriate plugins.

What methods do I need to call to register modules on `sys.path` with all the appropriate metadata, and how do I figure out what that metadata needs to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a setup.py for the package just as you would normally, and then use "setup.py sdist --formats=zip" to build your source zip.  The built source zip will include an .egg-info metadata directory, which will then be findable by pkg_resources.  Alternately, you can use bdist_egg for all your packages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for setuptools-based libraries you'll need to deploy the library's "Egg" metadata along with it.  The easiest way I've found is to deploy a whole [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv/1.3.3) environment containing your project and the required libraries.

I did this process manually and added this code to main.py to initialize the site-packages folder in a way that `pkg_resources` will work:

```
import site
site.addsitedir('lib/python2.5/site-packages')
```

However, you could try [appengine-monkey](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-monkey/wiki/Pylons) which automates most of this for you.

Answer (score 0):

On your local development system, run `python setup.py bdist_egg`, which will create a Zip archive with the necessary metadata included. Add it to your `sys.path`, and it should work properly.